# How to upload a file from project folder regardless of the OS(Windows or Unix) When the tests are executed on Selenium Grid

Tags: java, selenium, unix, jenkins

I wrote a test(Selenium WebDriver with java) in which I have to upload a file from the OS file explorer(upload window).

I used,

```
String path =System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator +"TestDoc"+File.separator+"File.pdf";
```

It works on my local(Windows Machine), but gives an error when I try run on a AWS server using Jenkins.

```
error: NullPointerException.
```

After debug what i saw was its taking my local machine folder address
`(C:\Users\...\...\TestDoc\File.pdf)`

Is there any other way that could upload the file from project folder, with the folder address of that particular machine, regardless ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your tests on grid, and the location of the file is on remote machine different OS and Tests are executed on a different OS machine , then you should let your remote driver know that the file that needs to be uploaded is residing on local machine and not on remote machine.

```
    String path =System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator +"FolderName"+File.separator+"File.pdf";
    WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("'fileUploadField'"));
    RemoteWebElement ele=(RemoteWebElement) ((RemoteWebDriver)baseSeleniumTest.driver).switchTo().activeElement();
    ele.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector()); 
    ele.sendKeys(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```java
String path =System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator +"FolderName"+File.separator+"File.pdf";
WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("'fileUploadField'"));
El.sendKeys(path);
```